# Hilt java.lang.Integer cannot be provided without @inject constructor or @Provides - annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

Hello I'm building the app with hilt dependecy injector, but when I try to build the app i had error from the title. Here's my code:

Flow class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "flows_table")
data class Flow @Inject constructor(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id:Int, val name:String, val duration:Int, val actions:ArrayList<Action>)
```

Action class:

```
data class Action @Inject constructor(
    val type: String,
    val color: String?,
    val brightness: Int?,
    val duration: Float
)
```

My application:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class YeebumApplication : Application() {
     //get bulbs repository
     private val bulbsDatabase by lazy { BulbsDatabase.getInstance(this)}
     val bulbsRepository by lazy { BulbsRepository(bulbsDatabase!!.bulbsDao()) }

     //get flows repository
     private val flowsDatabase by lazy { FlowsDatabase.getInstance(this) }
     val flowsRepository by lazy { FlowsRepository(flowsDatabase!!.flowsDao())}
}
```

My Fragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ActionDetailsFragment : Fragment() {


    @Inject
    lateinit var flow: Flow
```

With the activity everything works perfectly, but when I try to inject dependiences in fragment android studio throw that exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the Hilt annotation processor comes across the `@Inject` annotation in your fragment it is going to try and find (from a Hilt `@Module` with a `@Provides` annotated method) an instance of `Flow`.

I'm assuming from the error message you have not created this, so instead Hilt will move to the next option and try and create and instance of `Flow` itself.

So Hilt looks at the first property of `Flow`, `id` of type `Int`. And just like with the injection of `Flow` in your fragment, it repeats the process. It looks for an instance of `Int` from a Hilt `@Module` with a `@Provides` annotated method. This doesn't exist. Next option, try and construct it itself. Well `Int` is a platform type, you have no access, so you haven't created an `Int` class with an `@Inject` annotated constructor.

Hilt is now out of options and throws this `Exception`:

> Hilt java.lang.Integer cannot be provided without @inject constructor or @Provides - annotated method